# Set attr(name) in an element found in HTMLString

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I save in `html_data`variable `HTML`code using `Jquery`. Especially

```
Jquery(document).ready(function(){

     html_data = $('.row').html();

)};



<div class = "row">
  <div class = "col-md-12">
    <select multiple="multiple" id ="sel1">
      <option value="1"> Element1 </opion>
      <option value="2"> Element2 </opion>
      <option value="3"> Element3 </opion>
    </select>
   </div>
</div>

<div class ="before"></div>
```

Then I have a function in `Jquery` where I write

```
function newRow(){
    new_html = html_data;
    $(new_html).find('select').attr('name', 'myNewSelect');
    $(new_html).insertBefore('.before');
}
```

The new `row` with the `select multiple` are created but the attribute name is not be set. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you do not need to get the `html()` of `.row` element.
You can use `.clone()` method of jquery and then append it before `.before` using the same `.insertbefore()` method

```
function newRow(){
var new_html = $('.row .col-md-12').clone(true);
new_html.insertBefore('.before');
new_html.find('select').attr('name', 'myNewSelect');
}
```

Here is the fiddle: [https://jsfiddle.net/eL43e2vs/](https://jsfiddle.net/Anknit/xzz4bog8/)

Comment: I will try it and I hope I can set the name.. thanks

Comment: Can you please tell me the clone what returns to new_html ??? The select multiple element ?

Comment: It returns a jquery object which is a clone of the jquery node object of html inside the `.row` element. No it returns `div.col-md-12` node jquery object

Comment: When I click to insert it I get as result Object object xmmm

Comment: Be careful about the **id**. If you clone the html you will have two **ids** with the same value. IDs should be unique.

Comment: Yeah thank you. I edited your post. Maybe you should consider the id problem too.

Comment: I need a bit assistance. I have made some changes as I want them and I have as a result this https://jsfiddle.net/xzz4bog8/47/ . But when I try to add a new row then this new row replace the old. I want  to continue add more rows with select multiple.... Please can help me ?

Comment: You again need to use `.clone()` method inside newrow function . I have updated the fiddle . See working https://jsfiddle.net/Anknit/xzz4bog8/66/